# How to fix black screen(background) by RDP remote(Remmina) From 20.04.4 LTS to windows server 2016

Tags: server, windows, screen, rdp, remmina

I am getting this error on the Windows 2016 server: "Your background is currently turned off by the remote desktop connection. How can I fix it?"

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4?   An upgraded 20.04 or *focal* system has reported itself as 20.04.5 for some time now (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ will show the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded before that date).  I'd suggest applying all security updates & fixes to your system.

Comment: RDP: your background is currently turned off by remote desktop connection windows 10 https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2340